# Multivariate essential singularities

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function, where $U=\mathbb{C}^n\setminus Z(g)$ for some polynomial $g$.

If $n=1$, then either $f$ is meromorphic at a point $p$ in $Z(g)$, or it has an essential singularity, in which case every point in $\mathbb{C}$ except for 1 (or 0) are hit by $f$ in any small ball around $p$.

I have a two questions on what can happen if $n>1$:

1. Let $g_1$ be an irreducible component of $g$, and suppose that $f$ is not meromorphic along $Z(g_1)$, i.e. $g_1^kf$ cannot be extended to an analytic function defined on a Zariski open part of $Z(g_1)$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Is it true that for a general point $x\in Z(g_1)$, the restriction of $f$ to an arbitrary line through $x$ has an essential singularity at $x$, in sense of the single variable theory?
2. Is there some version of the Great Picard Theorem in multiple variables? Of course a positive answer to the previous would yield something in this vein, but I'm wondering if there are any nice theorems in the spirit of Picards theorem that deal with multivariate functions (so without restricting to a line or something similar).